# SUM and Differences SQL Tables

Tags: c#, sql

i have 3 table tblTaille

```
BNT       ref       Size
a         104545      25
c         304654      50
a         104545      70
c         704564      75
```

tblTaillePointage

```
BNT       ref       Size
a         104545      20
c         304654      0
a         104545      70
c         704564      75
```

tblDefectue

```
BNT       ref       Size
a         104545      1
c         304654      50
c         704564      0
```

i want to have this :

```
BNT       ref       Size
a         104545      4
c         304654      0
c         704564      0
```

which means where BNT and ref equals in tblTaillePointage, tblDefectue, tblTaille display it as a single row, and to get 4, (25 + 70 - (20+70+1)

I tried this query, but it did not produce the desired results:

```
SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT, SUM(size1), SUM(size2), SUM(size3), SUM(size4), SUM(size5), SUM(size6), SUM(size7), SUM(size8), SUM(size9), SUM(size10), SUM(Total)
FROM tblTailleALL
GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT
```

Comment: SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT, 

  SUM(size1),
  SUM(size2),
  SUM(size3),
  SUM(size4),
  SUM(size5),
  SUM(size6),
  SUM(size7),
  SUM(size8),
  SUM(size9),
  SUM(size10),
  SUM(Total)
  
FROM tblTailleALL
GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT

Comment: there is some columns i havent put on because it will be too long.

Comment: @user2967732 The most likely reason for the downvotes is that you did not show what you have tried in the body of your question, although you did try something, as your comment shows. It's best to show your attempt in the question, because it is generally easier and more instructive to correct your mistakes than to write code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `UNION ALL` on the three tables, selecting the `size` from the last two with a negative sign. After that, you could group by `ref` and `btn`, and put the sizes in the `SUM()`, like this:

```
SELECT btn, ref, SUM(size) FROM (
    SELECT btn, ref, size FROM tblTaille
UNION ALL
    SELECT btn, ref, -size FROM tblTaillePointage
UNION ALL
    SELECT btn, ref, -size FROM tblDefectue
) all_data
GROUP BY btn, ref
```

Here is a [demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5eca/1).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
  SELECT t.BNT, t.ref, SUM(t.size) - SUM(tp.size) - SUM (d.size) as Size
    FROM tblTaille t
    JOIN tblTaillePointage tp 
      ON t.BNT = tp.BNT 
     AND t.ref = tp.ref 
    JOIN tblDefectuetp d 
      ON t.BNT = d.BNT 
     AND t.ref = d.ref
GROUP BY t.BNT, t.ref
```